# Variance approximation for large scale least squares problems

Tags: variance, least-squares, covariance, large-data

The least squares problem I am solving has the objective function $S=\sum_i (y_i-f_i(\textbf{x},\boldsymbol{\beta}))^2$. The variance for this can be approximated as $\text{var}(\beta_j)\approx\frac{S}{n-m}([F^TF]^{-1})_{jj}$ where $n$ is the dimension of $\textbf{y}$ and $m$ is the dimension of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and we have covariance $F_{ij}=\frac{\partial f_i(\textbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\beta})}{\beta_j}$. However, in my code this $y_i$ corresponds to grey values of large images (e.g. $2000^2$), and thus it is computationally infeasible to evaluate this entire matrix explicitly. I was wondering if there was any literature on variance approximations for extremely large scale least squares problems, e.g. somehow leveraging the fact that only diagonal entries of the inverted matrix are necessary